# Add existing multiple Object to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, object, jframe

Hi i want to create different objects and place them in a single JFrame. There will be same type objects and different type objects. They change their place and existing by time. Do you have any example or documentation for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please review the Java Swing tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Try to be more specific with your question 'There will be same type objects and different type objects. They change their place and existing by time' won't make much sense to people who are used to programming and their daily work involves writing code.

Comment: Initially there will be random number 2D robots in area. They will throw projectile. If they will be shooted they kill and disable.

Comment: This is a programming question. You need to figure out how to implement the 2D robots to do this. Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682931/how-to-make-an-animation-with-swing) link for Java Swing examples. You may consider using JavaFX for this as well incase you decide not use Java Swing.